# Unix timestamp wont work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Before i used `datetime` for post created time from database,

```
SELECT MONTH(created)+1, count(*) 
FROM post_comments
WHERE YEAR(created) = YEAR(CURDATE())
group by MONTH(created)
ORDER BY MONTH(created)
```

and now i am using `unix timestamp`. How I need to make a change in the above code, to work it `unix timestamp`.

Before the created time looks like this: `2018-04-28 09:03:02`

and now the created time looks like this: `1524921263`

Comment: Do you want to format it sql side or php side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert everything to dates using [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))+1, count(*) 
FROM post_comments
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))
ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created));
```

I find it odd that you are adding 1 to the month in the `SELECT`.

You can change the `WHERE` to:

```
WHERE created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE), '-01-01')))
```

In general, it is a good idea to avoid the use of functions on columns.  This is less important when you are selecting a significant number of rows (unless the column is a clustered index).

Comment: You better of using the Unix time stamp for the where if  there’s any significant amount of data vs a subfunction

Comment: @gordonlinoff the `WHERE created` without `YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))` ?

Comment: I mean, using a function to  cast every value in the table as a year, and then comparing the result vs, doing a between jan 1 and dec 31 on that year, but just leaving the range in timestamp format for the sake of comparing INTS and\or using an index.  Search first, group later

Comment: @Azzo . . . Yes, as in the last example.